# Template suggestions showing up in Twig Debug, but not pulling in files

Tags: theming

I am using some preprocesses to add template suggestions for Views that are a child of a Paragraph type.

```php
function riverside_theme_suggestions_views_view_alter(&$suggestions, &$vars) {
  if (isset($vars['view'])) {
    if (isset($vars['view']->child_of_paragraph)) {
      $suggestions[] = 'views-view--' . $vars['view']->child_of_paragraph;
    }

    if (isset($vars['view']->child_of_paragraph_field)) {
      $suggestions[] = 'views-view--' . $vars['view']->child_of_paragraph_field;
      $suggestions[] = 'views-view--' . $vars['view']->child_of_paragraph . '--' . $vars['view']->child_of_paragraph_field;
    }

    $suggestions[] = 'views-view--' . $vars['view']->id();
    $suggestions[] = 'views-view--' . $vars['view']->id() . '--' . $vars['view']->current_display;
  }
}

function riverside_preprocess_paragraph(&$vars) {
  foreach ($vars['content'] as $field => $field_content) {
    if (isset($field_content['#field_type']) && $field_content['#field_type'] == 'viewsreference') {
      $field_content['0']['contents']['#view']->child_of_paragraph = $vars['paragraph']->bundle();
      $field_content['0']['contents']['#view']->child_of_paragraph_field = str_replace('field_', '', $field);
    }
  }
}
```

I can then see in my console, that those suggestions are coming through as I would expect:

[image: screenshot of theme suggestions in twig debugger]

However, if you look in my file structure, I have files matching the names on the 'File Name Suggestions:', but they're not being pulled in.

[image: file structure of my views templates]

If I create the file 'views-view--events.html.twig' or 'views-view--events--block-2', those will work as expected. Is there something else I'm missing? I'm wondering if there is a character limit on the template names? If so, is there somewhere to increase the character limit?

Comment: Replace all `-` with `_` in `$suggestions[]`

Comment: Thank you so much leymannx! That did it! Everything is working now.